# Issue with @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, configuration

I have created a spring boot application and I am trying to get images from external folder on disk, here is my code:

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan
 public class WebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 private static String UPLOAD_DIR = "D:\\upload";


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + UPLOAD_DIR+"/");
}
}
```

But when I launch the application, I got this error message:

```
> o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: No mapping for GET /myapp/index
> o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error
> page for request [/] as the response has already been committed.
```

Even if I remove @EnableWebMvc and I extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport directly, I am getting the same issue.

1. Why am I getting this issue?
2. Is it possible to get images from external resources without using @EnableWebMvc or WebMvcConfigurationSupport?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved the problem. Firstly I removed @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurationSupport, then I noted that there was an issue in the url. I put :

```
.addResourceLocations("file:/opt/files/");
```

Instead of:

```
.addResourceLocations("file:///C:/opt/files/");
```

As I am a Windows user.

Thanks